# Add Images in the react-native-modal-selector

Tags: react-native

I created a modal using `react-native-modal-selector`, but there is not any props or method defined to add the Images or Icons in the `react-native-modal-selector` document. Is there any other way to add the Images or Icon in the `react-native-modal-selector`?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, `react-native-modal-selector` provides the functionality to pass custom view. Use `customSelector` prop.

Example here: https://github.com/peacechen/react-native-modal-selector/blob/master/SampleApp/App.js#L74

Comment: it's overwriting the initialValue and nothing else doing

Comment: can you show me the proper demo for adding the images

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will allow you to add images or icons to the `react-native-modal-selector`.

```
let data = categories.map((category, index) => (
  {
    key: category.id,
    label: category.name,
    component: <View style={styles.row}><Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: category.icon }} /><Text>{category.name}</Text></View>,
    accessibilityLabel: category.name
   }))
```